# How do I limit the amount of document of a schema in Sanity?

Tags: sanity

For example, i have a schema called 'Blog'. i don't want there to be multiple 'Blog' entries, and only allow one entry.

```
export default {
  name: 'blog',
  type: 'document',
  title: 'Blog',
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'title',
      title: 'Title',
      type: 'string',
    },
    {
      name: 'content',
      title: 'Content',
      type: 'array',
      of: [{ type: 'block' }],
    },
  ],
}
```

according to the doc

> The `type: 'document'` property tells the studio that it should make it possible to make new animal documents.

i tried to remove type: 'document' from the schema, but got an error.